# How to start and stop a thread

Tags: python, multithreading

How can I start and stop a thread with my poor thread class?

It is in loop, and I want to restart it again at the beginning of the code. How can I do start-stop-restart-stop-restart?

My class:

```
import threading

class Concur(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stopped = False
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        i = 0
        while not self.stopped:
            time.sleep(1)
            i = i + 1
```

In the main code, I want:

```
inst = Concur()

while conditon:
    inst.start()

    # After some operation
    inst.stop()

    # Some other operation
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is David Heffernan's idea fleshed-out. The example below runs for 1 second, then stops for 1 second, then runs for 1 second, and so on.

```
import time
import threading
import datetime as DT
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def worker(cond):
    i = 0
    while True:
        with cond:
            cond.wait()
            logger.info(i)
            time.sleep(0.01)
            i += 1

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='[%(asctime)s %(threadName)s] %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%H:%M:%S')

cond = threading.Condition()
t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(cond, ))
t.daemon = True
t.start()

start = DT.datetime.now()
while True:
    now = DT.datetime.now()
    if (now-start).total_seconds() > 60: break
    if now.second % 2:
        with cond:
            cond.notify()
```

Answer (score 23):

You can't actually stop and then restart a thread since you can't call its `start()` method again after its `run()` method has terminated. However you can make one pause and then later resume its execution by using a [`threading.Condition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#condition-objects) variable to avoid concurrency problems when checking or changing its running state.

`threading.Condition` objects have an associated [`threading.Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects) object and methods to wait for it to be released and will notify any waiting threads when that occurs. Here's an example derived from the code in your question which shows this being done. In the example code I've made the `Condition` variable a part of `Thread` subclass instances to better encapsulate the implementation and avoid needing to introduce additional global variables:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import threading
import time

class Concur(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Concur, self).__init__()
        self.iterations = 0
        self.daemon = True  # Allow main to exit even if still running.
        self.paused = True  # Start out paused.
        self.state = threading.Condition()

    def run(self):
        self.resume()
        while True:
            with self.state:
                if self.paused:
                    self.state.wait()  # Block execution until notified.
            # Do stuff...
            time.sleep(.1)
            self.iterations += 1

    def pause(self):
        with self.state:
            self.paused = True  # Block self.

    def resume(self):
        with self.state:
            self.paused = False
            self.state.notify()  # Unblock self if waiting.


class Stopwatch(object):
    """ Simple class to measure elapsed times. """
    def start(self):
        """ Establish reference point for elapsed time measurements. """
        self.start_time = time.time()
        return self

    @property
    def elapsed_time(self):
        """ Seconds since started. """
        try:
            return time.time() - self.start_time
        except AttributeError:  # Wasn't explicitly started.
            self.start_time = time.time()
            return 0



MAX_RUN_TIME = 5  # Seconds.
concur = Concur()
stopwatch = Stopwatch()

print('Running for {} seconds...'.format(MAX_RUN_TIME))
concur.start()
while stopwatch.elapsed_time < MAX_RUN_TIME:
    concur.resume()
    # Can also do other concurrent operations here...
    concur.pause()
    # Do some other stuff...

# Show Concur thread executed.
print('concur.iterations: {}'.format(concur.iterations))
```

Answer (score 5):

The implementation of `stop()` would look like this:

```
def stop(self):
    self.stopped = True
```

If you want to restart, then you can just create a new instance and start that.

```
while conditon:
    inst = Concur()
    inst.start()

    #after some operation
    inst.stop()
    #some other operation
```

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start) for `Thread` makes it clear that the `start()` method can only be called once for each instance of the class.

If you want to pause and resume a thread, then you'll need to use a [condition variable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#condition-objects).

Comment: It is in loop, I want to restart it again at the beginning of the code. How can I do start-stop-restart-stop-restart ?

Comment: his "main code" does attempt to restart the thread in a loop.

Comment: will wait and notify methods result in busy-wait ?

Comment: I have done def wait(self) : self.wait() and def notify(self): self.notify(). After caling wait and then notify, error is emitted "recursion depth is too much"

Comment: You need to use a condition variable. So that you can do a non busy wait.