# How do I kill a thread that was started with thread.start_new_thread

Tags: windows, multithreading, python-2.7

How do I kill a thread that was started with thread.start_new_thread? Thank you!

```
import thread

def test_thread():
    for i in range(100):
       sleep(1)
       print('time %r' % time())
    print('%r' % 'thread is done')

thread.start_new_thread(test_thread,())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729498/how-to-start-and-stop-thread) is the solution to my problem where the Thread can be paused and resumed on demand.

Comment: I want to kill it, not pause or resume